# What is happening when I apply 5V DC to the DC end of a 12V AC to DC adapter?

Tags: usb, charger, 12v, adapter, 5v

The question is in itself a little bit confusing but I will try my best.

So I have a normal 12 volt (1 amp) AC to DC wall charger, nothing fancy about it. I use that to power a fan, which works great since it's made for it :)

So for the weird part, I also have a regular power bank USB (5V 2 amps) which I can connect perfectly to the fan also which works flawlessly. *But* when I attach the powerbank to the fan and have the 12V AC to DC plugged into the fan but NOT in the wall (the 12V AC to DC adapter is not connected to the wall outlet) then my powerbank simply shuts off?

I am incredibly curious how a hanging AD to DC charger that has no power can draw away all the power? In my own mind I thought that as long as a charger was not connected to a wall outlet there was no closed circuits.

What mystery or shall we say components may be inside that charger that is hijacking our power from the powerbank?

EDIT:

I tried a few other (AC to DC) wall chargers and they all seem to hijack the power from the powerbank in pretty much the same manner.

Comment: Yes, it can "hijack" power from powerbank - it depends on that how the adapter is made (it means - what is the circuit design inside). So, what you expect from us?

Comment: you can solve the mystery very easily by opening the charger enclosure

Comment: @jsotola I acutally really would like to but no way of doing so without breaking it :(

Comment: It is never a good idea to connect the outputs of two power supplies together whether one is shut off or not. This site is for answering specific electrical engineering design and theory questions, not for explaining how to use or why not to misuse products. I am voting to close the question.

Comment: The obvious suggestion is to ensure that you have the polarity of the 5V power bank the same way around as the polarity of the 12V power supply.

Comment: @DwayneReid Oh i actually never tried changing positive and negative cables to opposite side, that may just be it, good catch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most AC-to-DC power supplies have no problem when being back-fed with voltage that is less than or equal to the normal output voltage of the supply. This feature is often used when putting two identical DC power supplies in parallel so as to have redundancy.

The problem that you are having strongly suggests that the 5V power supply is wired backwards to the 12V supply.

Note that it is usually okay to have a lower-voltage power supply connected in parallel with the higher-voltage supply **SO LONG AS THE HIGHER-VOLTAGE SUPPLY IS TURNED OFF**

In other words, it's usually okay for the lower-voltage supply to back-feed the higher-voltage supply but **NOT** the other way around.